# Why did Henry Evans continue to go by Derrial Book?

Tags: names, firefly, serenity

In *Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale*, we learn that

> Shepherd Book was born Henry Evans and that he stole the identity of Derrial Book in order to join the Alliance as a Browncoat spy.

However, he continues to go by Book even after

> he was discharged from the Alliance.

It seems odd that he would continue to go by a stolen name after finding religion. Is there anything to indicate why he did this?

Comment: Doesn't the title pretty much give away the text in the first spoiler block?

Comment: Not really - it only gives away that Book had a different name once - not the reason or anything else about Book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why doesn't he re-assume his old identity?

Henry Evans is wanted by the police for (erm...) *crimes unknown*. These crimes are evidently serious enough to merit the Alliance send nine police fliers after him and no less than 6 heavily armed men to arrest him at his home. We can reasonably assume that **if he was to become Henry again, he would be immediately at risk of arrest and substantial sentencing.**

[image]

### Why doesn't he assume *another* identity?

Ignoring the fact that **he may simply not want to** (his childhood was awful) or that **stealing someone's identity would be quite difficult** (the last time he did it involved killing someone), the reality is that Derrial Book is sufficiently well known that he is recognised in public, a decorated military man with a long track record of service. **If he were to assume a *third* identity, that in itself would be highly suspicious behaviour that could lead to his arrest and trial where his other identity (and possibly his crimes against the Alliance) would be uncovered.**

Comment: None of this explains why Shepherd Book's ID got him medical care on an Alliance cruiser.

Comment: @HowardMiller He was a high ranking Alliance officer. I believe it's mentioned that his mistake wasn't made well-known in order to not make the Alliance look bad.

Comment: @HowardMiller - He was [discharged without trial](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxyC9.png). Presumably as an ex-high-ranking officer, his ID still has certain privileges.